# Re-installation failed due to different application signatures - Released app

Tags: android

My app is released and being used. I moved the development folder from my E: drive to C: drive and updated the various links to the libraries.  Works great, but when I try and push it to the phone that has the previous version I get the above error.

As this is released I don't want the users to have to uninstall the app.  There is a database where they have been storing info, and even though they are supposed all backup, someone will forget.

If I copy the APK to the phone, and then install it, it over writes the existing version without notice.

I seem to remember something like this when my workspace got corrupted and I seem to remember having to rename or delete a file or something.

the debug.keystore in the .android is the same file with a date from several months ago, so I don't think that is the problem.

**Output end of the two APKs verifying jarsigner.exe, these are the only lines that are different that I can see.**

```
   13821 Tue Apr 26 19:20:30 PDT 2011 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   13874 Tue Apr 26 19:20:30 PDT 2011 META-INF/CERT.SF
     955 Tue Apr 26 19:20:30 PDT 2011 META-INF/CERT.RSA


  14429 Tue Apr 26 14:04:54 PDT 2011 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   14482 Tue Apr 26 14:04:54 PDT 2011 META-INF/CERT.SF
     955 Tue Apr 26 14:04:54 PDT 2011 META-INF/CERT.RSA
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically this only occurs if you changed the key you signed with OR you changed the values of android:sharedUserId, android:sharedUserLabel or application process in the AndroidManifest.xml.

If you did change any of those you are out of luck.

Comment: i dont think I changed any of these as I dont even know where to find them.  Can you tell me where to look?

Comment: the 1st 2 are in the manifest and I assume the process is too.  But I do not have any of these value defined.

Comment: If you have the original APK lying around, you can do this: jarsigner -verbose -certs -verify <apk file> on both of them and verify that the certificate details are identical (same DN and validity period) between the 2 apks. If they are identical, then I'm really stumped.

Comment: The only lines I can see different are at the very end:

Comment: Truly odd: those are fine, those aren't certificate-dependent. I'm not sure there's a way to check the signature of the package on the phone, but that would be the next suggestion. See if you can copy the apk off the phone with adb pull and then run jarsigner on it as well.